# Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-button-toggle'. in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have angular 9 application.

And I am using angular-material. and the module: MatCheckboxModule

And I also imported the MatCheckboxModule in the correct module.

I am using this material package:

```
"@angular/material": "^10.2.0",
```

But I still get this error:

```
Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-button-toggle'.
```

So I have this:

```
 <div class="menu">
         <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" value="contours" (change)="toggleLayer($event)">
           contours</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" value="museums" (change)="toggleLayer($event)">
        museums</mat-button-toggle>
    </div>
```

and this is my module:

```
 MatCheckboxModule,
    
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class DesktopDashboardModule {}
```

and this I have in app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavBarComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatIconModule,
    DesktopDashboardModule,
    MobileDashboardModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
```

So and of course I googled this. But I just found that this is the right solution.

So what I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You're talking about [mat-checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) but using a [mat-toggle-button](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api), which binds to a value - not checked on individual items. If you refer to the docs you will see it indeed does not have a `checked` property.

Comment: What do you mean. I have this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mapbox-gl-ar7vd8?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fexamples%2Ftoggle-layers.component.ts and then toggle-layers.component. They also use mat-button-toggle . So what I have to change then?

Comment: please make sure your imports are correct, `import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';` after making changes in modules make sure to serve your app again using `ng serve`.

Comment: Oke , solved by adding this:  MatButtonToggleModule,

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your imports are correct.

```
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
```

after making changes in modules make sure to serve your app again using `ng serve`